# How to make PhpStorm (JetBrains) enforce case sensitivity of function names in PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm

It's probably not a big deal but I think the code should be consistent and I think case sensitivity is important for function calls. Is their a way to get PhpStorm to identify if a function call does not have the same case as it's definition?

Occasionally I find functions like `updateNote` looking like `updateNOte` due to my right hand typing faster than my left. I want to catch these and fix them.

PhpStorm finds a lot of other syntax items like data types and such, but I can't find an inspection for this. Does such an inspection exist?

Comment: Interesting, I had (incorrectly, I guess) assumed that PHP would already throw an undefined error if the case didn't match considering it does so with variables.

Comment: I would say it will probably be pretty hard to get PHPStorm to warn you about, so I would suggest just not worrying about it so much as the code still _works_, but make a conscious effort to fix any that you come across

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So while not intentional to answer my own question I finally found (after over an hour of searching and 5min after posting to stack overflow) a built in inspection for this in PHPStorm.

1. Settings (Preferences on Mac)
2. Editor
3. Inspections
4. PHP
5. Code Smell (seriously this is what the category is called)
6. **Method call or class usage is not case sensitive**

It is turned off by default and stored under an odd but perhaps good name.

Comment: tnx ... i was lost in stupid preferences trying to find this , since my left hand is as random as your right hand typing.

Comment: Thanks, I like that I can now alt-enter and clean it up on the fly - smells better now.

Comment: For anyone on a Mac: Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections -> PHP -> Code Smell -> Case mismatch in method call or class

Comment: @PatrickQ updated my answer. Thank you. Also realized I missed the "editor" part which is also on windows.

Comment: @danielson317 Ah, okay, so basically the same then.  Wasn't sure if that was one of those weird differences they have on each platform.

Comment: Found it at: `Case mismatch in method call or class usage`

Comment: PhpStorm on Ubuntu, version 2021.3
The inspection has been renamed to "Case mismatch in method call or class usage" and is now placed under Code Style - NOT Code Smell